# Undefined is not an object N.ScaleNone Error on Android with expo-av

Tags: android, expo, react-native

I'm using Expo managed workflow, version 38.0.8 and expo-av 8.2.1, I'm getting this error **only on android**, when I sent to production via OTA. Video format is .mp4 [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just passed a second argument, overrideFileExtensionAndroid, in video source and solved my problem[image]